Поиск совпадений при помощи findall, начинающихся с конкретного символа
Добрый день.
Я имею вот такой скрипт:
import re
f = open('all.txt', 'r', encoding='ANSI')
trim = re.findall('[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
print (trim)

Я ищу в текстовом файле все совпадения с указанными символами, но кроме этого, я хочу ввести условие, чтобы функция findall искала только совпадения, которые начинаются с определённого символа, например, начиная с буквы "c".
Как мне это сделать?

'[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}' -> 'c[0-9a-zA-Z_]{4,}'.

Или '(?=[cC])[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}'

@u111 Тогда вопрос должен звучать по другому: найти совпадения, которым предшествует заданный символ.

@Vitalizzare, это почему?

@u111 Сорян, ошибся. Непривычно видеть (?=...) в начале, а не в конце паттерна. По инерции принял его за (?<=...). Но, кстати, поэтому я бы его и не использовал - слишком усложняет и без того непростое чтение регулярных выражений.
